# appending rows to tableView from within a block

Tags: ios, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to add/append rows to a single section of a tableView from within a block.
The problem is that when I add the index paths (insertRowsAtIndexPaths) the code crashes (The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1) yadayadayada)

Now I traced it back to the fact that the [weakSelf.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] is not updated after I appended the extra data to its data source (also using weakSelf)

Anyone knows what I'm missing here?

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

_tipSearchController.searchResultBlock = ^(NSArray *tips, BOOL firstBatch) {
    weakSelf.noLocationsAfterSearchFilters = NO;
    if (firstBatch==YES) {
        [weakSelf.tips removeAllObjects]; // empty datasource if required
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }

    NSUInteger currentTipCount=weakSelf.tips.count;
    [weakSelf.tips addObjectsFromArray:tips]; // adding data to datasource.

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tips.count; ++i) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+currentTipCount inSection:0]];
    }

    // Crash here ;(
    [weakSelf.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

};


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tips.count;
}
```

Comment: Please post your numberOfRowsAtIndexPath method

Comment: Does this block run on the main thread? If not, try to dispatch to update of data source and tableViewInsertion to the Main thread.

Comment: Yeah it does run in the main threat but I found that somehow the "numberOfRowsInSection" is not called on self (as weakSelf would suggest)....

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that `searchResultBlock` gets executed on the main thread as @mbo42 mentioned.
Second, wrap rows insertions in `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates`:

```
[weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
NSUInteger currentTipCount=weakSelf.tips.count;
[weakSelf.tips addObjectsFromArray:tips]; // adding data to datasource.

NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tips.count; ++i) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+currentTipCount inSection:0]];
}

[weakSelf.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
```